# How to access Camera in mobile devices(android, IOS, etc.) and in desktop in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do i access camera in mobile devices and in desktop computer using MVC 4 website? for capturing image only and how to identify the camera. I have tried using this  code below. But it is not working on IOS and its not capturing image.

```
<script>
    // Put event listeners into place
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            errBack = function (error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
            };

        // Put video listeners into place
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
        else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
    }, false);

    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function () {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 6 and onward, you can just use an input tag as such:

```
<input type="file" />
```

It'll lauch / allow access to the camera / photos.